# Content won't load when using action the_content

Tags: actions, the-content

When I use add_action( 'the_content'...

The content of the page just won't load. Also the content I am trying appears in all kinds of places in the page. Why?

Is there a way to force it to only appear under my post?

```
function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'wp_footer', array(&$this, 'loadRatingsJs') );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_valnetincGetRatings', array(&$this, 'getRatings' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_valnetincGetRatings', array(&$this, 'getRatings' ) );
    //add_action( 'the_excerpt', array(&$this, 'getRatings' ) );
    add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$this, 'getRatings' ) );
}

public function getRatings($content)
{
    //echo $postID;
    if(function_exists('the_ratings')) {
        /*if(is_null($postID))
        {
            the_ratings();
        } else {
            the_ratings('div', $postID);
        }*/
        $rating = the_ratings();
        return $content.$rating;
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, it would help to see the actual relevant code. what does the function you hook to the_content action do? do you call the_content function in your loop?

Answer (score 2):

`the_content` is not an action, it is a filter. You should be concatenating a string and returning it. It sounds like you are `echo`ing content directly.

That is:

```
// wrong
function test_content($content) {
  echo 'this is wrong';
}
add_filter('the_content','test_content');

// right
function test_content($content) {
  return 'this is right '.$content;
}
add_filter('the_content','test_content');
```

Comment: the fact that `add_action` and `add_filter` are interchangeable adds a nice layer of confusion.

Comment: Using filter works. But again the new content appears in many places in the page. I just want it to appear for the post content. Also it now only shows on top of the post and not at the bottom like I would like. I tried to interchange the var but nothing works.

Comment: @Milo : I completely agree. `add_action` and `add_filter` should be distinct.

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins : you are going to ___have to post your code___ if you want a more specific response to your question.

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem is that you don't return anything if your conditional fails:

```
public function getRatings($content)
{
    //echo $postID;
    if(function_exists('the_ratings')) {
        /*if(is_null($postID))
        {
            the_ratings();
        } else {
            the_ratings('div', $postID);
        }*/
        $rating = the_ratings();
        return $content.$rating;
    }
}
```

To simplify:

```
public function getRatings($content)
{
    // Conditional
    if(function_exists('the_ratings')) {
        // Do stuff
        // Return modified content
        return $content.$rating;
    }
}
```

The problem is: you don't return anything if `the_ratings()` function doesn't exist. You need to account for that condition:

```
public function getRatings($content)
{
    // Conditional
    if(function_exists('the_ratings')) {
        // Do stuff
        // Return modified content
        return $content.$rating;
    }
    // Condition is false;
    // Just return the original content
    return $content;
}
```

An even simpler way (perhaps) is to return *outside* the conditional, and only *modify* inside the conditional:

```
public function getRatings($content)
{
    // Conditional
    if(function_exists('the_ratings')) {
        // Do stuff
        // Modify content
        $content .= $rating;
    }
    // Return content, modified or unmodified
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Actually the the_rating does output something. What used to not output anything was the post... But now it works. the only problem I still have is that the_ratings() content does not output at the bottom of the post but at his top. It also appears at other places in the page.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and add those clarifications - especially as they relate to the up-voted comment.